# SQL Server 2008 avg of top data from other columns and unique column data

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by, subquery, average

Forgive me as I'm sure there's some simple group by or sub query that I'm missing but I can see to solve the following and need some help.

I have data in a table and need to return the distinct value from PointName with the average values in `AdjEasting, AdjNorthing & AdjHeight` (which are average values of the top 4 returned values from each column where PointName value exists)

So far I have this data:

```
PointName,AdjEasting,AdjNorthing,AdjHeight
51,76672.47700,36190.37870,128.54820
51,76672.47800,36190.38060,128.55070
51,76672.47680,36190.38010,128.55020
51,76672.47640,36190.37910,128.55020
51,76672.47690,36190.37930,128.54990
51,76672.47740,36190.38050,128.54990
52,76781.27600,36069.18870,127.80420
52,76781.27580,36069.18800,127.80350
52,76781.27580,36069.18930,127.80310
52,76781.27630,36069.18900,127.80370
52,76781.27630,36069.18870,127.80330
53,76905.20930,35932.21400,126.79920
53,76905.20910,35932.21290,126.79970
53,76905.20550,35932.21180,126.79950
53,76905.20820,35932.21350,126.80080
53,76905.20910,35932.21380,126.79920
53,76905.20830,35932.21370,126.80160
55,77050.28410,36001.64670,128.73920
55,77050.28400,36001.64790,128.73990
55,77050.28440,36001.64590,128.74010
55,77050.28400,36001.64650,128.74010
55,77050.28360,36001.64590,128.74010
55,77050.28500,36001.64780,128.73990
55,77050.28630,36001.64760,128.74200,
55,77050.28430,36001.64630,128.73960
```

...and I want this data:

```
51,76672.47705,36190.37963,128.54983
52,76781.27598,36069.18875,127.80363
53,76905.20803,35932.21305,126.79980
55,77050.28413,36001.64675,128.73983
```

This is the query I have but it returns a distinct ID but then the same averaged values for each record in ID:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    PointName
    ,(SELECT avg(AvEasting)
      FROM
         (SELECT TOP 4
              cast(AdjEasting as float) as AvEasting
          FROM AdjFile
          ORDER BY PointName, epoch desc) AdjFile)
    ,(SELECT avg(AvNorthing)
      FROM
          (SELECT TOP 4
               cast(AdjNorthing as float) as AvNorthing
           FROM AdjFile
           ORDER BY PointName, epoch desc) AdjFile)
    ,(SELECT avg(AvHeight)
      FROM 
          (SELECT TOP 4
              cast(AdjHeight as float) as AvHeight
           FROM AdjFile
           ORDER BY PointName,epoch desc) AdjFile)
FROM AdjFile</P>
```

**EDIT**

I can get a single value to return using this code:

`SELECT
    PointName
    ,avg(AvEasting)
    ,avg(AvNorthing)
    ,avg(AvHeight)
FROM

        (SELECT TOP 4
            PointName
            ,cast(AdjEasting as float) as AvEasting
            ,cast(AdjNorthing as float) as AvNorthing
            ,cast(AdjHeight as float) as AvHeight
         FROM AdjFile 
         ORDER BY PointName,epoch desc) AdjFile
GROUP BY PointName
ORDER BY PointName`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, ***PLEASE*** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! That way, you don't need any of the messy `<p>` and `<br/>` tags, either!

Comment: To me, looks like cursor and a #temp table needed

Comment: BTW, you still didn't mention how do you determine... what is making an item a Top-4 item.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with your approach, how about something like this:

```
SELECT af.PointName,
(SELECT AVG(Top4AdjEasting) AS AvEasting FROM
(SELECT TOP 4
 CAST(af2.AdjEasting AS FLOAT) AS Top4AdjEasting
 FROM AdjFile af2
 WHERE af2.PointName = af.PointName
 ORDER BY Top4AdjEasting desc)),
(SELECT AVG(Top4AdjNorthing) AS AvNorthing FROM
(SELECT TOP 4
 CAST(af3.AdjNorthing AS FLOAT) AS Top4AdjNorthing
 FROM AdjFile af3
 WHERE af3.PointName = af.PointName
 ORDER BY Top4AdjNorthing desc)),
(SELECT AVG(Top4AdjHeight) AS AvHeight FROM
(SELECT TOP 4
 CAST(af4.AdjHeight AS FLOAT) AS Top4AdjHeight
 FROM AdjFile af4
 WHERE af4.PointName = af.PointName
 ORDER BY Top4AdjHeight desc))
FROM AdjFile af
GROUP BY af.PointName
ORDER BY af.PointName
```

Does that work for you?

Comment: Sorry no, I get syntax error messages. I copied the exact text into MS SQL Server management studio and got this: 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have the AdjFile table to work with, so I'm going by blind reckoning.  Can you get one of the inner subqueries to work for a specific PointName value?  Can you get one of the outer subqueries to complete the averaging?  Please let me know where I tripped up over the syntax, so I can do better next time.

Comment: The content of the entire table is shown at the top of the question except its formatting but generally its all nvarchar(20). I can get a single value to retun using the code I added to the question above.